# Is $\Bbb R^2 - \{x_1, \dots, x_{2n-1}\}$ homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee_{i=1}^{2n-1} S^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X \subset \Bbb R^3$ be the union of $n$ lines through the origin. Compute $\pi_1(\Bbb R^3 − X)$.

As $X$ can be deformation retracted to $S^2$ with $2n$ holes. Let $\{x_1, \dots,x_{2n}\}$ be the removed points. Few questions I have are

1. Is it so that $S^2 - \{x_1, \dots, x_{2n}\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2 - \{x_1, \dots, x_{2n-1}\}$?
2. Is $\Bbb R^2 - \{x_1, \dots, x_{2n-1}\}$ homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee_{i=1}^{2n-1} S^1$?

If these two statements are true, then $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(\Bbb R^2 - \{x_1, \dots, x_{2n-1}\}) \cong \pi_1(\bigvee_{i=1}^{2n-1} S^1)=\Bbb Z * \dots *\Bbb Z$ $2n-1$ times.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes. 1 is just stereographic projection through $x_{2n}$. There is probably also a clever way to see 2, however, the only thing I came up with is using Seifert-van Kampen. For $n=1$ the statement is clear. For larger $n$, you can find two open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ such that one contains just one point you remove and the other one containing all the others and their intersection is simply connected (for example you seperate one point from the others by a line and then consider two open neighborhoods of the respective half-spaces). Then, by Seifert-van Kampen you have that
$$\pi_1(\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}) = \pi_1(\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})\ast\pi_1(\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x_n\}) = \mathbb Z \ast \dots \ast \mathbb Z, $$
$n$-times.