# How to prove that $S^2-\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{2n}\} $ as a deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^3 -X ?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I found  the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493669/is-bbb-r2-x-1-dots-x-2n-1-homotopy-equivalent-to-bigvee-i-1)

Let $X \subset  \mathbb{R}^3$
be the union of $n$ lines through the origin. Compute $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 − X)$

**My thinking**: Deformation retraction of $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ onto $S^2$  is given  by

$f_t:\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$  defined  by

$f_t(x)=  (1-t)x+ t\frac{x}{|x|} $ where $t \in [0,1]$

**My question** :  How  do we show  that $S^2-\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{2n}\} $  as  a  deformation  retract of $\mathbb{R}^3 -X $  where  $x_1,x_2,,....,x_{2n}$  are the  $2n$ points  in the intersection $X \cap S^2$

finally my question is that  how  to prove that $S^2-\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{2n}\} $  as  a  deformation  retract of $\mathbb{R}^3 -X ?$

Comment: The same homotopy works. Each such line intersects the sphere at exactly a pair of antipodal points.

Comment: @Laz okay thanks you.Actually  i was confused